# Join a list of strings in python and wrap each string in quotation marks

Tags: python, string, list

I've got:

```
words = ['hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice']
```

I want to have:

```
'"hello", "world", "you", "look", "nice"'
```

What's the easiest way to do this with Python?

Answer (score 317, accepted):

Update 2021: With f strings in Python3

```
>>> words = ['hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice']
>>> ', '.join(f'"{w}"' for w in words)
'"hello", "world", "you", "look", "nice"'
```

Original Answer (Supports Python 2.6+)

```
>>> words = ['hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice']
>>> ', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in words)
'"hello", "world", "you", "look", "nice"'
```

Comment: @Meow that uses `repr` which is a lil hacky in this specific case as opposed to being clear with the quotes

Comment: @jamlak ok, repr just seemed safer to me incase you have quotes in your string.

Comment: @Meow good point about the quotes, I guess that this one has the advantage of being explicit while the other approach does support the quotes thing

Answer (score 79):

You can try this :

```
str(words)[1:-1]
```

Comment: how does it add quotes?

Comment: This adds single quotation marks instead of double, but quotes inside the words will be automatically escaped. +1 for cleverness.

Answer (score 57):

you may also perform a single `format` call

```
>>> words = ['hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice']
>>> '"{0}"'.format('", "'.join(words))
'"hello", "world", "you", "look", "nice"'
```

Update: Some benchmarking (performed on a 2009 mbp):

```
>>> timeit.Timer("""words = ['hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice'] * 100; ', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in words)""").timeit(1000)
0.32559704780578613

>>> timeit.Timer("""words = ['hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice'] * 100; '"{}"'.format('", "'.join(words))""").timeit(1000)
0.018904924392700195
```

So it seems that `format` is actually quite expensive

Update 2: following @JCode's comment, adding a `map` to ensure that `join` will work, Python 2.7.12

```
>>> timeit.Timer("""words = ['hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice'] * 100; ', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in words)""").timeit(1000)
0.08646488189697266

>>> timeit.Timer("""words = ['hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice'] * 100; '"{}"'.format('", "'.join(map(str, words)))""").timeit(1000)
0.04855608940124512

>>> timeit.Timer("""words = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] * 100; ', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in words)""").timeit(1000)
0.17348504066467285

>>> timeit.Timer("""words = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] * 100; '"{}"'.format('", "'.join(map(str, words)))""").timeit(1000)
0.06372308731079102
```

Comment: does this have a better performance than the one proposed by jamylak?

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: @sage88 No it isn't. Preoptimization is evil, there is a 0.0000001% chance that the miniscule speed difference here is the entire bottleneck of a Python script. Also this code is much less intuitive so it is not *better*, it is *very slightly faster*. My solution is more pythonic and readable

Comment: @marchelbling Benchmark is invalid because jamylak' solution works also for iterables of non-strings. Replace `.join(words)` with `.join(map(str, words))` and show us how that goes.

Comment: @JCode updated the benchmark. The gap is smaller but there still is a 2x gain on my machine.

Comment: @marchelbling Keep in mind that `map` in Python 2 returns a `list` but in Python 3 `map object` generator is returned. I suggested `map` to express the idea and I didn't know that you used Python 2.

Comment: If there are no items in the list this returns `""` empty double quotes instead of an empty string.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> ', '.join(['"%s"' % w for w in words])
```

Comment: Format is available since python 2.6.

Answer (score 7):

An updated version of @jamylak answer with F Strings (for python 3.6+), I've used backticks for a string used for a SQL script.

```py
keys = ['foo', 'bar' , 'omg']
', '.join(f'`{k}`' for k in keys)
# result: '`foo`, `bar`, `omg`'
```

Comment: Works, but is it considered to be the canonical pythonic way ?

Comment: @MarcelFlygare Yeah `f` strings seem to be the best way now

Answer (score 1):

find a faster way

```
'"' + '","'.join(words) + '"'
```

test in Python 2.7:

```python
    words = ['hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice']

    print '"' + '","'.join(words) + '"'
    print str(words)[1:-1]
    print '"{0}"'.format('", "'.join(words))

    t = time() * 1000
    range10000 = range(100000)

    for i in range10000:
        '"' + '","'.join(words) + '"'

    print time() * 1000 - t
    t = time() * 1000

    for i in range10000:
        str(words)[1:-1]
    print time() * 1000 - t

    for i in range10000:
        '"{0}"'.format('", "'.join(words))

    print time() * 1000 - t
```

The resulting output is:

```
# "hello", "world", "you", "look", "nice"
# 'hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice'
# "hello", "world", "you", "look", "nice"
# 39.6000976562
# 166.892822266
# 220.110839844
```

Answer (score 1):

```
words = ['hello', 'world', 'you', 'look', 'nice']
S = ""
for _ in range(len(words)-1):
    S+=f'"{words[_]}"'+', '
S +=f'"{words[len(words)-1]}"'
print("'"+S+"'")
```

OUTPUT:

```
'"hello", "world", "you", "look", "nice"'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solution and for me we should choose wisely...

```py
items = ['A', 'B', 'C']

# Fast since we used only string concat.
print("\"" + ("\",\"".join(items)) + "\"")

# Slow since we used loop here.
print(",".join(["\"{item}\"".format(item=item) for item in items]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
# Python3 without for loop
conc_str = "'{}'".format("','".join(['a', 'b', 'c']))
print(conc_str) 

# "'a', 'b', 'c'"
```

Comment: This is a blatant duplicate to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008055/15521392)....10 years later.